# Cakephp uploading an image, the tmp_name file is getting deleted before the script is done?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, upload

I have an html form that allows the user to browse for a file to upload.

In the cakephp script, I use move_uploaded_file() to upload the file from the temp location to a location on the server.

```
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $url);
```

However, the file seems to be disappearing before the upload is complete:

> move_uploaded_file(/img/recipes/5.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP\app_controller.php, line 97]
>
> move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpF25A.tmp' to '/img/recipes/5.jpg' [APP\app_controller.php, line 97]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's telling you that the *target* does not exist. `/img/recipes/5.jpg` is hardly a valid directory to upload to on UNIX system, it's probably completely invalid on Windows.

You'll need to build an absolute path to save the file in (like `C:\webroot\project\images\foo.jpg`) instead of a URL.

Comment: The server is on ubuntu server edition, as for the target path, I thought that cakephp's url redirect feature would automatically formulate that into a proper url, guess not then. I'll look into it. Oh wait, I just realized I put a slash in front of the path ><

Comment: @Razor The `move_uploaded_file` function has nothing to do with Cake or its Router. Also, URLs have nothing to do with file system paths. Sorry, you'll have to construct a valid path yourself, there ain't *that* much magic in Cake. :) You can use some of [Cake's constants](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1141/Core-Definition-Constants) to get a directory relative to the app.

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining about the non-existence of /img/recipes/5.jpg, not the source file (that's uploaded by the user).